# delay the script until it pings to an ip without sleep

Tags: python, time

I am working on a modem, will change the settings and will reboot the device(All this done in script). So, i need to ping the system and wait until the device is up.

What i tried is

```
cur = time.time()
delay = cur + 300
while delay > cur:
    t = os.system('ping '+ip)
    if t:
        something here
    else:
        something else here
```

Is there any other way to do it? Basic question is, how can wait for some timeout, till a device is up!

Note: I looking for a solution without time.sleep

Answer (score 1):

try use `time.sleep()` like so:

```
import time 

delay = 1 # this will delay for 1 seconds
time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: i am looking for a method without sleep.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid using sleep, you could just change the while loop to continue until you get your ip

```
waiting =True
while waiting:
    counter =0
    t = os.system('ping '+ip)
    if t:
        waiting=False
        do something
    else:
        counter +=1
        if counter == 10000: # this will prevent an never ending loop, set to the number of tries you think it will require
            waiting = False
```